# C++ my program reads backspace as a character

Tags: c++, passwords

I am working with a c++ program, but I am stuck with annoying bug. The bug is that when i type the password, it counts backspace as a character so can I fix it? Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string password, username, lon, nu, np;
  char c;
  int StarNum = 0, humanproof;
  cout << "Do you wanna create a user or login?";
  cout << "\nLogin" << endl;
  cout << "New" << endl;
  cin >> lon;
  if(lon=="login"){
    goto login;
  }
  if(lon=="new"){
    goto newa;
  }

  login:
  cout << "Username: ";
  cin >> username;

  lol:
  cout << "Password: ";
  while (c != 13)
  {
    c = (char)getch();
    if(c == 13) break;
    StarNum++;
    password += c;
    cout << "*";
    if (c == 127 || c == 8){
      //go here to fix the problem
    }
    password = "";
    goto lol;
  }
}

if(username == "user" && password == "pass" || username == nu && password == np){
  cout << "\nYou are logged in.";
  goto options;
} else {
  cout << "\nusername or password is wrong" << endl;
  return 0;
}
return 0;

newa:
cout << "Username:";
cin >> nu;
cout << "password:";
cin >> np;
cout << "Type the number fourhoundred and twentie three too proof you are a human: ";
cin >> humanproof;
if(humanproof == 423){
  cout << "The username is " << nu << endl;
  for(int no = 0; no <= 100; no++){
      cout << endl;
  }
  goto login;
  return 0;
}
if(humanproof!=423){
  cout << "wrong answer!";
  return 0;
}
options:
    int op;
    cout << "\nwhat do you want to do?" << endl;
    cout << "1. Calculator" << endl;
    cout << "2. About"<< endl;
    cout << "3. Just for fun" << endl;
    cout << "4. Exit" << endl;
    cin >> op;
    if(op==1){
        goto calculator;
    }
    if(op==2){
        goto info;
    }
    if(op==3){
        goto fun;
    }
    if(op==4){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        cout << "you entered a invalid number. " << endl;
        return 0;
    }

calculator:
double n1, n2, sum;
int opa;
cout << "Choose a operation" << endl;
cout << "1. Addition/+" << endl;
cout << "2. Subscraction/-" << endl;
cout << "3. Multiplication/x" << endl;
cout << "4. Divsion/ /" << endl;
cin >> opa;
if(opa == 1){
    cout << "enter number 1" << endl;
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "enter number 2" << endl;
    cin >> n2;
    sum = n1 + n2;
    cout << "the sum is " << sum;
    return 0;
}
if(opa == 2){
    cout << "enter number 1" << endl;
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "enter number 2" << endl;
    cin >> n2;
    sum = n1 - n2;
    cout << "the sum is " << sum;
    return 0;
}
if(opa == 3){
    cout << "enter number 1" << endl;
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "enter number 2" << endl;
    cin >> n2;
    sum = n1 * n2;
    cout << "the sum is " << sum;
    return 0;
}
if(opa == 4){
    cout << "enter number 1" << endl;
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "enter number 2" << endl;
    cin >> n2;
    sum = n1 / n2;
    cout << "the sum is " << sum;
    return 0;
}
if(opa > 4){
  cout << "You entered a invalid number";
  goto calculator;
}
info:
    cout << "Created by Bergur 2013";
    return 0;

fun:
    cout << "You want an eyepad(ipad)?";
}
```

Comment: Yuck! Remove the goto statements.

Comment: Please format your code. Also: do you *really* need to show ALL of it? Delete all irrelevant parts.

Comment: Make your code more readable by using '\r' instead of 13 and '\b' instead of 8.

Comment: http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already checks:

```
while (c != 13)
```

And prevent newline from being handled, do similar to what you need with the backspace character, whose number is 8

To fix your issue, before:

```
StarNum++;
```

Add:

```
if (c == 8 && StarNum > 0) {
 StarNum--;
 if (password.size () > 0) 
  password.resize (password.size () - 1);
 continue;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but how do I remove it?

Comment: So do `cout<<'\b';` followed by `cout<<' ';` and `cout<<'\b';` again, it will go back one character, remove the character, then move back again

Answer (score 0):

Please format your code. Also, try to provide a minimal code which reproduce the problem, not the whole code.

Unrelated to your problem

- Try not to use goto.
- Do not use ASCII values, but use the char literals instead, i.e. use '\n' instead of 13.

Also, you can simply add an iother condition inside your while:

```
while (c != '\n' && c != ' ')
```

Comment: More like _never_ use goto

Comment: Yeah but how do I remove it?

Comment: and also how do I get somewhere without using goto?

Comment: @user3119614 You'll need to redesign your entire program in order to get it to work properly without using `goto`s. Yes, that's how bad gotos are! :)